# Customize jenkins' project's weather report

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I have project (which has one robotframework job) that fails one time on about N times (N is about 200 in my case). It's not cool, but I have to accept it for now. I'd like to customize weather reports to something like this: if project fails 1 in N times, it's sunny, but if it fails twice within last N runs, it's not sunny anymore. Tested device changes its settings quite often, so I can't provide any failure counters to robot's job. Does jenkins or any of jenkins' plugins offer project's weather report customization?

Comment: you can configure your plugins for changing your build into sunny status. In example for HTML publish report (clover PHP), in advanced config you can set your params for modify your fail's limit... this kind of configuration is available for many plugins. When you built your app, check the fail's steps, and make modification on concerned plugins

Comment: With theses plugins, I can set how many tests in 1 build may fail. The thing which I want to make is on different level. I want to set how many jobs in 1 project may fail. If i click on project, I want to see red dots next to failed jobs, but If number of failed job didn't exceed my limit, project's report should be is still sunny.

Answer (score 0):

Set thresholds and optionally disable thresholds for critical tests only to count every test in the pass percentage.

goto "your project/configure" and select "Post-build Actions -> Publish Robot Framework test results",for the last to set "Thresholds for build result  "